How to delete edges of curve based on their length

How to link geometric nodes into curves and control neighboring values to generate curves?
How to set a value to control whether two points that are too far apart should not be linked together?
Source file download

You could read the edge length and delete it if it's too big. Did you try that ?

Thank you for your answer. I don't quite understand geometric nodes. I'm still learning. Can you help me demonstrate it? Download the source file

Please revert the edit and just ask a new question. Edits shouldn't change the problem,  especially if someone already addressed the original one

The process is as follows :

Convert to mesh (useful for deletion)
Delete edges (set on Edge, not on Point)
Convert back to curves


Then the 3 nodes in the black frame works as follows :

Edge Vertices gives us the 2 vertices of the current edge
Distance computes the distance between the 2 vertices, which is the edge length
Greater Than tests if the distance is greater than some custom value


Thank you for your answer, but I cannot use greater than to delete it because I have longer edges. I need to use the smallest vertex between them to link them, and set the distance less than how much to link the vertices

I'm getting tired of you not explaining correctly your question, working a solution, then you explaining that your issue is more complicated. Pls start by explaining with more than 2 sentences in your question and then, maybe, I'll write an answer.

Thank you for your answer. Sorry, the question has been added
